# Time Complexity of this dijkstra algorithm?

Tags: python, time-complexity, dijkstra

What is the time complexity of this Dijkstra code seeing that the priority queue can get as big as |E|? (Nodes are likely to be added more than one time to the priority queue) I want to reason the time complexity inside the while loop.

```
def shortestReach(n, edges, start,target):

    adjList = collections.defaultdict(list)

    for parent, child, cost in edges:
        parent -= 1
        child -= 1
        adjList[parent].append((child, cost))
        adjList[child].append((parent, cost))

    priorityQueue = queue.PriorityQueue()
    priorityQueue.put((0, start))
    visited = set()
    while priorityQueue.qsize() > 0:
        costPar, parent = priorityQueue.get()

        if parent == target:
            return costPar

        if parent in visited:
            continue

        for adj in adjList[parent]:
            child, cost = adj
            if child not in visited:
                priorityQueue.put((cost + costPar, child))

        visited.add(parent)
```

My idea: Since priorityQueue can get as big as |E|, then the line below can happen at most |E| times but the nodes taken from the queue wont be processed since we have a visited set check. so it is |E|log|E|

```
costPar, parent = priorityQueue.get()
```

the for loop below can at most run at |E| times since each node is processed once only due to the visited set so the reasoning is that it can take up to |E|log|E| times at most

```
for adj in adjList[parent]:
            child, cost = adj
            if child not in visited:
                priorityQueue.put((cost + costPar, child))
```

the overall time complexity is 2*|E|log|E| -> O(|E|log|E|)?

Comment: `O(|V| + |E|log|E|)` ?

Comment: @DaniMesejo can you tell me your reasoning?

Comment: How is your priority queue implemented?

Comment: @DaniMesejo its the standart pq in Python, it has O(log|size|) time complexity for every operation, with a min heap

Comment: Notice that the while is not going to do more operations that O(|E|), right? So |E| * log |E|

Comment: @DaniMesejo true, I have added a reasoning to the original problem can you tell me if that makes sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner loop is executed at most once for each vertex. The total number of its iterations is the sum of degrees of each vertex, which is equal to twice the number of edges. As a result, it is executed at most `2*E` times.

The line `priorityQueue.put((cost + costPar, child))` inserts a node in a heap, which is a `O(log(size_of_heap))` operation. Note that `size_of_heap<=E`

Combining the above, we get `O(|E| * log |E|)`